# Using Aspose To Open PST files & Copy Structure

Tags: c#, aspose, pst

I have an input folder full of msg email files, within these there are `inbox, outbox, sent items` etc.

Is there any way I could use aspsoe to open the PST copy the files and structure to an output folder.

I have tried

```
PersonalStorage personalStorage = PersonalStorage.FromFile(InputFolder);
// Get the folders information
FolderInfoCollection folderInfoCollection = personalStorage.RootFolder.GetSubFolders();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Inbox, Sent Items, Outbox, etc. are predefined folders and are referred to by StandardIpmFolder. You can use the following code sample to extract messages from these and save to disc.

```
PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.FromFile("pstfile.pst");

//Get Default Inbox Folder
FolderInfo fiInbox = pst.GetPredefinedFolder(StandardIpmFolder.Inbox);

//the same way you can get StandardIpmFolder.Sent and others

//traverse and save to disc
MessageInfoCollection msgs = fiInbox.GetContents();

foreach (MessageInfo msg in msgs)
{
    MapiMessage mapi = pst.ExtractMessage(msg);

    mapi.Save(mapi.Subject + ".msg");
}

pst.Dispose();
```

Please try it and if you still face some issue, you can write to us on [Aspose.Email](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) forum along with your sample PST file for further assistance.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

To export the entire Structure of the PST i used this recursive traversal:

```
 internal static Dictionary<string, MapiMessage> ReadPstAspose(string pstPath)
    {
        PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.FromFile(pstPath);
        Dictionary<string, MapiMessage> allMessages = new Dictionary<string, MapiMessage>();
        GetAllMessagesRecursive(pst, pst.RootFolder, allMessages);
        pst.Dispose();
        return allMessages;
    }


    private static void GetAllMessagesRecursive(PersonalStorage pst, FolderInfo folder, Dictionary<string, MapiMessage> allMessages)
    {
        foreach (var messageEntryId in folder.EnumerateMessagesEntryId())
        {
            try
            {
                MapiMessage message = pst.ExtractMessage(messageEntryId);
                var key = $"{message.DeliveryTime:ddMMyyyy:hhmmss}\\{folder.RetrieveFullPath()}\\{message.Subject}";
                allMessages.Add(key, message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        foreach (var subFolder in folder.GetSubFolders())
        {
            GetAllMessagesRecursive(pst, subFolder, allMessages);
        }
    }
```

The code ist mostly copied from the excellent documentation at [aspose.com](https://docs.aspose.com/email/net/read-outlook-pst-file-and-get-folders-and-subfolders-information/).

There's still the issue of re-creating the structure. The key of the dict has the structure in it and you can go from there to rebuild it anyway you like.